# How to count a list of unique values with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a counter to count unique values based on conditions. I haven't been sucessufel because I didn't wanted to use VBA.
I have this Table:

[image: img1]

And I want to count the Colum "Nr. Pacote" but the unique values. For that I've been successful, but I also want to count the unique values on that colum but using the conditions on the columns "Estado" and "Par/Impar".

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Comment: Sounds like your looking for `COUNTIFS`. Can you post what you've tried so far and your expected outcome?

Comment: In addition to @cybernetic.nomad's suggestion, have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: @cybertic.nomad @Jbowman I've already tried the pivot table and `countifs` it doens't work. 
The problem with using them is that it counts the number of cells, not the individual cells. So it will count for example the number 15 twice. 
I have a solution for counting them without conditions, but with conditions I've been unsuccessful.
For counting without conditons I use this:  `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A11:A20;A11:A20))-1` .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count only unique values in A1:A10 that has a corresponding "x" value in B1:B10, you can check out the following formula:

```
=ROUNDUP(SUMPRODUCT((1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10))*(B1:B10="x")),0)
```

The `ROUNDUP` is used to consider a decimal value as 1 since there's a value among those duplicates that meet the criteria "x" in B1:B10. The B1:B10="x" addition just cancels out all values in A1:A10 that doesn't meet the criteria.